Can I compose classical works on a DAW?
I played a bit of guitar, but my guitar finally gave up the ghost. I'm interested in composing a fugue and recreating works like Asturias or The Faerie Queene but was wondering if I could do this solely with a DAW. Learning music theory (further) isn't a problem, but I'm not really trying to learn another instrument. I would like to compose music and hear it and maybe even recreate pieces I like, and since free DAWs exist, I was wondering if I could create pleasant music solely on DAWs.

Yes, you can create music in any style in a DAW, including classical styles.  But DAWs are designed for creating sound recordings, not sheet music.  If you want to have sheet music at the end for musicians to play, that will have to be done as a separate step.  If you want to input notes in standard notation, most DAWs will not support that (but some do... do your research on specific products).
Maybe what you are looking for is music notation software.  This will not typically generate quality recordings, but it will have a basic virtual instrument to let you hear your score.  After writing your music, you can hand it to a musician to record or import it into a DAW with a better sounding virtual instrument.

It's not only the quality of the virtual instrument that matters but also the deviations from strict time and pitch as well as subtle manipulation of volume that make a great performance great.  Yes, a better virtual instrument will sound better, but creating an expressive performance without an actual expressive performer is a huge job.  It may be just the project that Ethos is looking for, so I certainly don't mean this as criticism of this answer, but it's worth mentioning it so Ethos can approach it with open eyes.

Of course! You can write any style using any tools you like. Now, that does not necessarily mean that this is the best option for what you want to do with it. Ask yourself some questions:

What is the best way for me to get into a creative flow?
How do I balance creative flow with effective output?
Do I want to publish this somehow?
If so, how do I want to do it?

For instance, if you are looking to improvise something into a digital audio workstation and publish it as an audio file of a classical improvisation on a streaming service, your daw is exactly what you need.
However, if you want to publish a score for others to read and play, a DAW is only an initial tool for that process. Midi can tell you exactly what you played in the computer's language, but it can't account for humanity, and so it can't make good scores. You have to spend a good deal of time editing and recomposing in order to make a sensible score from a midi recording.
Here is how I compose, grossly simplified:

Improvise a melody at the piano
Practice the melody until I can do it reliably, editing throughout this process.
Write down your melody on paper
Work on motivic development, and flesh out phrasing away from the piano.
Improvise textures on piano
Write out textures
Combine textures and melody in a musescore file I labely my sketchbook. Elaborate and develop
Copy useful passages into my main musescore file, composing transitions as I need them.
Edit as needed.

Daws do not usually play into my process unless I am working on popular music for my band or experimental tracks that use interesting audio effects.
Hope this helps!

Your alternative, as others have said, is music notation software like Finale (sadly officially dead), Sibelius, Dorico, Musescore, etc. It can be tricky for a beginner to choose between music notation software and a DAW because "both can do both". But from someone who uses both, having begun in music notation software and gradually moving more towards DAW usage...
Music notation software is far better for what it sounds like: notating. Part of this is engraving and making it look nice. DAWs are not good at this. For example, here's Reaper's extraordinarily ugly notation view.

But it's not just about the looks. Some of the other things notation gives you are essential tools for composing orchestral (classical) music, such as:

Adding dynamics and articulations
Seeing your harmony vertically
Doing quick "smart edits" like separating or combining voices across staves
Adding and aligning lyrics
Working within a known time framework, e.g. designating notes as a tuple instead of them being "quantized" to combinations of dotted + tied notes
Using different clefs, different transpositions for concert pitch / transposing instruments

... Now, these things are often possible in DAWs through plugins, but with lots of fiddling and hacking things together and still with underwhelming results.
DAWs, on the other hand, specialize in playback / output. Some of the things that are easier to do in a DAW:

Adding effects globally or track-by-track, like reverb; mastering
Changing instrument voices, combining instruments, creating hybrid instruments
Changing relative volumes and pans (mixing) and automating those throughout the performance
Exporting in various formats, exporting stems, exporting segments of the project
Combining MIDI instruments with recorded audio in a single project

It's worth mentioning one playback feature where it's the other way around, though. Music notation software and/or specific instrument libraries often come with customizable "human playback" strategies that interpret the score and add realistic dynamics, tiny variations in volume or pitch or tempo, interpretations of trills and tremolos, bowing for stringed instruments, and all sorts of things that a producer just dealing with MIDI data would rather not touch. That said, they can touch them with a MIDI editor and make much finer and more intentional adjustments than music notation software can do, but composing and editing MIDI events are very different ballgames not equally enjoyed by all musicians.
Hence, many people will use a music notation software if they're thinking about the composing process and/or having real musicians be able to read it, and use its mediocre playback as a demo, while they will use a DAW to create complex productions and fine-tune what the final result sounds like. Any modern composition process is likely to use both in the workflow at different points.
If your goal is to write music that you will then perform on the guitar, or you have other musicians whose performances you want to capture, I'd suggest you write it in music notation software, then record and either send it to someone to master or do so yourself in a DAW. If your goal is more to produce audio tracks with synthesized instruments and/or effects, you could just start and finish in the DAW yourself. No wrong way to go about it, though.

BTW, if you're a good guitarist, you will find guitar playback from notation software particularly painful. It can be fine-tuned in a DAW and get decent results now in 2024 2025 with modern VSTs, but I find it's an instrument that gives away its fakeness quite easily.

The short answer is yes. Just listen to examples on these pages. I think you will judge them as "pleasant" sounding.
https://www.soundsonline.com/orchestral/symphonic-orchestra
https://www.vsl.co.at/masterpieces
https://www.spitfireaudio.com/virtual-instruments/bbc-symphony-orchestra-discover#listen
Beyond that I think your question becomes unclear as you dig into it. Is the sound output of the DAW mean to be a demo or the final product? Do you want "classical" music that uses real instrumental techniques? Do you what to compose in an historically authentic classical style? Question like these really have nothing to do with writing with pen and paper versus a DAW.
The tools are available to produce a very believable electronically emulated orchestra. Whether music created with them sounds "classical" will depend on the composer's knowledge of the historic style and instrumental techniques.
